# Reading text files in GUI entry fields

Tags: python, file, text, tkinter

I'd like to know of a way to read a text file and add its contents into a text box. I am doing this in tkinter, so I'd need to get the text in Python, and put it into the text box using tkinter, that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you having problem with reading file or do you have problem with tkinter or you have problems with interfacing them?

Comment: Its a problem with interfacing the text file. Im creating a restaurant pos system and I need the text in the text files to be shown in entry boxes in a GUI

Answer (score 2):

You would use [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) and [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open) to open the file and then [`Text.insert`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.insert-method) to put its contents in the textbox.

Below is a basic demonstration:

```
from Tkinter import Text, Tk
r = Tk()
t = Text()
t.grid()
with open("/path/to/file") as myfile:
    t.insert("1.0", myfile.read())
r.mainloop()
```

Comment: okay, so where would I put the amount of characters I want the text box to display? And how would I do that for multiple text boxes

Comment: @user3046997 - I don't know what you mean exactly.  If you want to set the height and width, you can use the `height` and `width` options like so: `Text(width=10, height=25)`.  Then, you could even attach a [scrollbar](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm).

Comment: I need the text to appear in the entry box basically

Comment: you are very unclear about what you are asking this time...
as iCodez said it is good enough to use the `width` and `height` attributes to set the box size and use a `scrollbar` and If you want to print some of the files data then read only that part of it.

Comment: @iCodez im not talking about the framework, I need a text file to be read inside an entry box on my gui!